# dispatch_async() "silently" failing -- why?

Tags: ios, dispatch-async

All:

I am wrestling with a `dispatch_async()` problem.  My goal is for a TableViewController (TopStoriesTVC) to display some rss feeds.  The xml fetching and parsing is factored into a class called Reporter.

TopSToriesTVC tells the Reporter to fetchNewsFrom:.  Once that's done, and the xml parsing is finished, the Reporter invokes TopStoriesTVC's fileStories:fromReporter: method.

```
           -(void) fetchNewsFrom:(NSString *)url
```

TopStoriesTVC ===================================>   Reporter

```
             -(void)fileStories: fromReporter:
           <===================================
```

This works great in a single-threaded environment.  But, I want to grab several rss streams, so instead of:

// In TopStoriesTVC ...

```
-(id)initWithNibName:bundle: {
     // stuff omitted
     [self.newsReporter fetchNewsFrom:TOP_STORIES_NEWS_URL];
     [self.sportsReporter fetchNewsFrom:TOP_STORIES_SPORTS_URL];

}
```

// in Reporter...

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{   
    [self.bureauChief fileStories:self.items fromReporter:self];
}
```

which works perfectly, I have tried to wrap them using `dispatch_async()`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self.newsReporter fetchNewsFrom:TOP_STORIES_NEWS_URL];
    [self.sportsReporter fetchNewsFrom:TOP_STORIES_SPORTS_URL];
});
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.bureauChief fileStories:self.items fromReporter:self];
});
```

Those don't work at all. I am using get_main_queue() because fileStories:fromReporter: includes a `[self.tableView reloadData];` statement, and I understand that needs to happen on the main thread.

When I say they "don't work at all", specifically, I get a) no error messages in the console, b) nothing in the tableView, c) my `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods aren't even being called, d) setting debugging statements just leads me into a bunch o' assembly language.

Can anyone spot what's going wrong here?  Or have any suggestions?  I really would appreciate it.

Comment: You can place a breakpoint inside your block. If you hit it, it means that your block is being run and that your problem doesn't lay with your dispatch.

Comment: Personally, in my project, I found that the problem wasn't in the `NSXMLParser` (which parses fine in the background queue), but in my `NSURLConnection`, which wasn't calling my delegate methods if I initiated the connection in the background queue. How are you downloading the data to be parsed and are you sure that's being completed successfully? Are you 100% sure the problem is in the parsing?

Comment: Rob, that answered my question -- when I wrote: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    });
}
it worked perfectly -- but if I used any other queue, it did not.  Weird ...  Incidentally, I wanted to mark your answer as correct, but it seems to have show up as a comment, so I couldn't.